# Generate a deterministic set of values from non-uniform distributions

Tags: python, sample, normal-distribution, probability-distribution

Numpy has some routines like `np.linspace` that creates an array of evenly spaced numbers.

Is there a similar way to generate non-evenly spaced numbers that follow a specific distribution like the normal or beta distribution? I know that there are lots of functions that can create a random sample, but I am looking for a deterministic set of values that fit a distribution.

For example, like this:

```
arange_normal(n=10, mean=10, std=1)
[1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 15, 19]
```

The numbers here are guessed, but the idea is that they would give a perfect fit for the specified distribution. Similarly, I would also be looking for something like `arange_beta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be looking for is the *quantiles* of the beta distribution. You can get them using SciPy's `scipy.stats.beta.ppf` method. The following code prints 20 evenly spaced quantiles:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
print(sp.stats.beta.ppf(np.linspace(0,1,20),a=0.5,b=0.5))
```

Note that other distributions, such as the normal distribution, cover either or both halves of the real line, so that their values at 0 and/or 1 may be infinity. In that case, you have to choose a slightly smaller domain for `linspace`, such as this example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
print(sp.stats.norm.ppf(np.linspace(0.001,0.999,20),loc=0,scale=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to compute the beta function's probability distribution function.

You can do so by simply applying scipy.stat's `beta.pdf` function on an numpy array defined by an arange. Example given below for `alpha = beta = 0.5`:

```py
from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np

def arange_beta(start, stop, step):
    x = np.arange(start, stop, step)
    return beta.pdf(x, a=0.5, b=0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant something different, i.e. how to generate a set of numbers whose distribution would fit a given the beta distribution.